# VB.net chosing serial port System.IO.IOException

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, arduino

I am trying to edit open source code i found, there is allot of bugs there, anyway i solve everything but i still have this one:
i put a combo drop-down menu to chose between serial ports to communicate with arduino, but it seems always the program chose COM5 if i chose other port or not.
this is the error i have when i press start button to communicate

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.dll
Additional information: The port 'COM5' does not exist.
```

and this is the combo drop-down menu code

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
                                              Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
End Sub
```

and this code for the start button

```
 Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) 
                                                              Handles Button7.Click
        SerialPort1.Open()
        SerialPort1.Write("~")
        SerialPort1.Write("LCD is working!")
        Timer2.Start()
        SerialPort1.Close()
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but it seems always the program chose COM5 if i chose other port or not. this is the error i have when i press start button to communicate

This code

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
End Sub
```

is intended to get the combo box index selected by a user and set which serial port they selected.  However, the body of that handler is empty, so it is not actually doing anything.

The code

```
Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
        SerialPort1.Open()
```

is presumably where the Exception is being thrown.  You have not changed the settings of SerialPort1 anywhere in the code you show.  Presumably, you should add some code to ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged to update the properties of SerialPort1 to reflect the COM port the user selected.